# Question about Enigma's rotors turnover

Tags: enigma

I've been trying to make an algorithm work like the real Enigma machine, fully customizable. I use two online emulators to check that my encoded message is correct :

- https://cryptii.com/pipes/enigma-machine
- https://www.101computing.net/enigma-machine-emulator/

Currently, without the plugboard, it seems that it works correctly... until some weird rotors configuration happens. So here is the exact setup :
The leftmost rotor is V
The middle rotor is I
The rightmost rotor is III

The initial configuration is ZPK. The ring setting is AAA.

After some letters, according to my algorithm, the rotor configuration goes:

- ZPV
- ZQW
- ZQX

I am aware of the double stepping mechanism, and 26 keys pressed later we should have

- ZQV
- ZRW
- ASX

BUT, both online simulation have this sequence:

- ZPV
- ZQW
- ARX

As is rotor I going from P to Q is the turnover, while all the other sources I've seen say it's from Q to R (Royal Flag Wave Kings Above...)

Am I crazy, or did I miss something?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The biggest problems with such questions are how we can sure that your code is correct and that kind of problem is off-topic here. I'm confused with the rotor configuration prints since we need only 3 characters shown on the top of the rotors.

Comment: Well, let's not talk about my code, in fact. My question is the following : Considering the rotors are V, I, III, how is it possible to get the following sequence : ZPV, ZQW, ARX ?

Comment: Rotors move like a counter, I don't see that in your sequence.

Comment: ZPV, ZQW, ZQX isn't like a counter? How is ZPV, ZQW, ARX more coherent regarding Enigma?

Comment: Uh, shouldn't that end with ZQB?

Comment: Yes, my mistake. Updated; ZPV, ZPW, ZPX, ZPY, ZPZ, ZQA, ZQB....

Comment: indeed, except that each rotor of Enigma has a different timing for rotating. Rotor III makes the rotor to his left increment when it goes from V to W, hence ZPV, ZQW, ZQX... as far as I understand. 
Rotor I (the middle one), increments the one to the left when it goes from Q to R. 
But the emulators all behave like it is P to Q, which drives me crazy

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enigma_rotor_details#Turnover_notch_positions

Comment: Exactly, so why are all the emulators doing another way?

Answer (score 1):

The sequence ZPV, ZQW, ARX is quite correct -- the first time the middle rotor turns is not due its own notch, but to that of the fast rotor (which indeed turns from V to W for "Wave"). Recall that the notch of the fast rotor when set to V allows the middle rotor's gear to be engaged.

Now when the middle rotor turns again one letter later, it is because of its *own* notch, which is exposed when the middle rotor shows the letter Q (preceding R for "Royal"). When a key is pushed, the lever engages the leftmost rotor's gear *and* the middle rotor's notch, turning both -- this is of course the famous double stepping anomaly.